# How to change the 'baseline hazard function' in coxph R

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I have implemented a gap time-conditional (aka PWP) recurrent Cox regression model in R. However, rather then baseline hazard function (delta_0(t)) acting as a constant, I would like to incorporate a probability distribution based on event time duration (this is something I have wrote myself) to ensure that the baseline hazard function is weighted by the duration at which an individual has been exposed to a certain number of events.

For example. When I consider 5 recurrent events the baseline hazard function is reset and I will have some risk associated with defined covariates. e.g., in R code:

```
coxph(Surv(tstart,tstop,status) ~ drug + cluster(id) + strata(enum), data=medicalDF)
```

In my work, this is a collection of medical event. The longer the individual has recurrent events the less risk they will be at having a new event (because they are undergoing treatment). For example, if you are having a 10th headache the probability of your headache lasting very long or being as potent is a lot less than the 5th headache you had.

I have spent a lot of time going through the R documentation. Is there anyway of modifying the underlying hazard baseline function?

Comment: this might be worth posting on cross validated, someone might be able to tell you how to modify baseline hazards there.

Comment: Thanks, Mike. It was a toss-up between software experience vs. stats knowledge.

Comment: Yea I agree it could go either place I think, but if you get no hits here try there

Comment: If I get what you want, then you want to down weight people with a lot of events as you know that these are less likely to have an event due to treatment (and not the severity/true likelihood of event which you are interested in). Moreover, you have some prior weights function for how much lower the risk is for these individuals. It seems like you can use the `weights` argument for this purpose. If I am correct, then you should just need to set the weights to the appropriate values at slightly before each time point at which there is an event.

Comment: Hi Benjamin! I do hope this is exactly what I want. It could be from how you described it. I'll tinker with my code and see how I get on then update accordingly.